# QGIS 3.22.1 changelog: physical DPI

Tags: qgis, dpi

The [3.22.1 changelog](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog322/index.html#id34) describes a new feature: *Allow using physical DPI for map canvas.*  Unfortunately, there is no description **how** to enable this feature.  I searched through the QGIS *Settings > Options*, but no joy.  Any advice?

Comment: Check this : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/6802#issuecomment-879843175

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This setting can be found in Options -> Canvas & Legend -> DPI -> Respect screen DPI.
Looks like the version information is not completely accurate.

[image: Respect screen DPI]

Comment: And how can this answer be better because answered by the developer himself !