# QGIS interface visual issues in later versions

Tags: qgis, gui

Comparing QGIS 3.22.8, 3.32.1, 3.34.3, all on the same machine (Windows 10), same settings and same monitor, the interface looks distorted on the latter 2 versions. Any idea why?

3.22.8- crisp visuals, text, WMS layer looks ok:

[image]

3.32.1- text is blurry, warning icon has no antialiasing, WMS layer looks horrible, menu text is very small, tool icons are big:

[image]

3.34.3- same as above. Everything very blurry or distorted:

[image]

Settings > Options > General > Application are the same across all versions:

[image]

Comment: That's really bizarre, I've never come across it when upgrading versions on Win 10. It's too inconsistent to seem like a Windows anti alias setting. But just to avoid doubt, have you checked that (a) Respect Screen DPI setting is the same (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417488/qgis-3-22-1-changelog-physical-dpi) and (b) Windows DPI scaling settings are the same (https://danantonielli.com/app-scaling-on-high-dpi-displays-fix-2019/) ? I don't think these are the causes but it's worth ruling them out.

Comment: @she_weeds thanks I'll check those links out, but in any case I can't expect each of my 100 users to perform adjustments in the settings of QGIS. So it might be I have to hold off updating.